# How do you view the value of a chart point on mouse over?

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have various points on a chart. I would like to be able to show the exact value of the point in a tooltip on mousing over that particular point.

Example:

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY("Jul", 600)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY("aug", 458)
```

On mousing over these points on the chart, the tooltip text should show "600" or "458".

**Edit:**

This gets me close but it only shows the value of the mouse position on the point, not the full value of the point:

```
 Private Sub Chart1_GetToolTipText(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ToolTipEventArgs) Handles Chart1.GetToolTipText
    If e.HitTestResult.PointIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
            MetroToolTip1.SetToolTip(Chart1, e.y.tostring)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realize you found a solution, but the simplest way is to set the 'Series.ToolTip' property.

`Chart1.Series(0).ToolTip = "#VAL{0.0}"`

The ToolTip makes use of *keywords* to define what value to display followed by an optional format specifier that follows the MS [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for the most part.  The easiest way to find these keywords is to use the editor exposed in the PropertyGrid to set the ToolTip.

In this example the `#VAL` tells it to display the y-value.  The `{0.0}` tells it to format the number using the "0.0" format string.

Edit:
I found a table on the Dundas site (MS bought the control from them), that lists the Keywords and explains more about the format specifier usage.
[http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1132](https://web.archive.org/web/20160826032118/http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1132)

Keywords documentation from MSDN: [Keywords [rs_vsDataVis]](https://web.archive.org/web/20170302064702/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx)

Comment: Simplest way wins. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code needed to show the point values:

```
Private Sub chart1_GetToolTipText(sender As Object, e As ToolTipEventArgs) Handles Chart1.GetToolTipText
    ' Check selected chart element and set tooltip text for it
    Select Case e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType
        Case ChartElementType.DataPoint
            Dim dataPoint = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points(e.HitTestResult.PointIndex)
            e.Text = dataPoint.YValues(0).ToString
            Exit Select
    End Select
End Sub
```